# How to log telnet traffic reliably?

Tags: logging, telnet, network-traffic

We have a pbx system that we can telnet into over the LAN.  We want to just dump the log of messages (calls) to a file.  We use Hyperterminal which can capture the txt to a file, but I need to do this manually whenever we restart the server.

Is there a piece of software (or a command line switch for hyperterminal) that will log a telnet session which can be started automatically?  It also needs to be reliable and able to run for weeks on end without disconnecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have it solved.  I just wrote a Delphi appliction to dump a telnet sessin to disk.

Seems to do what I want, only time will tell how reliable it is.

Once I have it up and running I'll post code to GIT